Sudo apt update fails to fetch amd package
While trying to install ROCm, due to it not working I tried reinstalling everything. AMD drivers, amdgpu-dkms etc. Now when I do apt update it throws this error:
Err:7 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.2.3/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
File has unexpected size (14796 != 14502). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 88.221.92.45443]
Hashes of expected file:
- File size:14502 [weak]
- SHA256:32d9e2c9b5937eeffa770e4300bbea6314c6892b14a1c2243616c8f035bc30ee
- SHA1:69855a7f3e64ab1dde7b0b623df7e090c54ef06f [weak]
- MD5Sum:e1937a8794545882ce8f1be9b7b279f1 [weak]
Release file created at: Fri, 04 Oct 2024 21:54:13 +0000
Hit:8 http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Fetched 5465 B in 1s (9174 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.2.3/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  File has unexpected size (14796 != 14502). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 88.221.92.45 443]
Hashes of expected file:
- File size:14502 [weak]
- SHA256:32d9e2c9b5937eeffa770e4300bbea6314c6892b14a1c2243616c8f035bc30ee
- SHA1:69855a7f3e64ab1dde7b0b623df7e090c54ef06f [weak]
- MD5Sum:e1937a8794545882ce8f1be9b7b279f1 [weak]
Release file created at: Fri, 04 Oct 2024 21:54:13 +0000
  E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I have AMD RX6800, was working on pytorch ML project and wanted to implement ROCm for better performance.

Did you read the messages?   A mirror sync maybe in progress, ie. the file on the mirror you're using may have been updating as you tried to download, trying again later (5-20 minutes later) may have worked perfectly.

I have a some problem with "https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.2.3/ubuntu noble/main amd64" - File has unexpected size. Ubuntu 24.04.1

"E: Failed to fetch https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.2.3/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  File has unexpected size (14796 != 14502). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 88.221.92.45 443]" This is something you can't do anything about.  Right now, the Radeon repositories' files don't match the expected size as detailed in the system - if this persists for more than 48 hours you have to contact Radeon to fix this, this isn't something we can fix.

I was worries it could have been my mistake maybe due to versions not being compatible or something. Will contact Radeon on this. Thank you.

I have the same issue. I found that you can download a previous version by browsing https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install. I went with 6.2.2 instead of 6.2.3, and I managed to get past the fetch issue. Will report later if the install was succesful.

Using a previous version worked very well.
